# Integrating anticaptcha with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, recaptcha

I am using Selenium/Python to try and fill out a form and than fill out the recaptcha. I found python-anticaptcha and bought $10 in credits, and everything is working, the captcha comes up, but than nothing happens. I tried to look for answers for a few hours/consulted their api and examples, but could not find anything. Ultimately, the captcha should work and then the website would generate a table which I am trying to web-scrape

This is what it ends up looking like, but nothing happens and after a minute or so it usually quits, this is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from python_anticaptcha import AnticaptchaClient, NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
import requests

url = "https://claimittexas.org/app/claim-search"
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
result = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lastName"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value='Al';",result)
time.sleep(2)
result.submit()

api_key = #MYAPIKEY
site_key = '6LeQLyEUAAAAAKTwLC-xVC0wGDFIqPg1q3Ofam5M'  # grab from site

time.sleep(2)
client = AnticaptchaClient(api_key)
task = NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask(url, site_key)
job = client.createTask(task)
job.join()
token = job.get_solution_response()
requests.post(url, data={'g-recaptcha-response': token}).text
```

Comment: Why do you create several profiles on SO to build your code? Yesterday you asked a question selenium and the same website using another brand new profile, as per https://stackoverflow.com/q/51014792/8240959. Are you sure what you're doing is legal?

Comment: Btw you should probably remove your api key unless you want to give away you credits to everyone...

Comment: found the answer?

Comment: yup thanks! @Volatil3

Comment: @ss77 you should put the answer pls?

Comment: @volatil3 posted last week, thanks

Comment: @piethon26 thanks, my issue is,  there is no submit. It shows on page, if I click on "Not a robot" and refresh then it does not show. How to simulate it via Selenium or requests?

Comment: you need use plugin to automatic solve captcha . you need add plugin to selenium .https://anti-captcha.com/apidoc/articles/how-to-integrate-the-plugin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of someone at anticaptcha.com, I solved this issue.

```
api_key = '....'
site_key = '6LeQLyEUAAAAAKTwLC-xVC0wGDFIqPg1q3Ofam5M'  # grab from site

client = AnticaptchaClient(api_key)
task = NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask(url, site_key)
job = client.createTask(task)
print("Waiting to solution by Anticaptcha workers")
job.join()
# Receive response
response = job.get_solution_response()
print("Received solution", response)

# Inject response in webpage
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "%s"' % response)

# Wait a moment to execute the script (just in case).
time.sleep(1)

# Press submit button
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit" and @class="btn-std"]').click()
```

Comment: This is not working. anticaptcha.com also provide javascript to do instead

Comment: maybe my site must use different mechanics. anyways the js injection could apply to any headless like puppeteer selenium ...

Comment: worked for me perfectly, thanks! By the way, why is there no information about these functions on their site? I found nothing ...