# Submitting reCAPTCHA v2 with selenium and python - no form submit button

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, recaptcha

So I recently signed up with anti-captcha and have been testing with the https://github.com/ad-m/python-anticaptcha/blob/master/examples/recaptcha_selenium.py script.

I cannot get past a reCAPTCHA that has no submit button (hidden or visible) nor a clear way to submit for verification. I've used the anti-captcha firefox plugin, so I know it can be passed. But I am stuck at the point of doing this manually myself.

I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51034252/integrating-anticaptcha-with-selenium) was going to be a helpful answer, but it doesn't go into depth. I am able to get the job.get_solution_response() token and enter it into the required `textfield`, but I cannot submit the "form."

Does anyone have success with this? I am also looking to do this in a headless version of the browser. Would a solution be different based on headless vs non-headless?

BTW, realtor(dot)com is the website I am having trouble with. If I am not aloud to post this site, please let me know so I can remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went back into the source code of the site and found they are using a function as a callback for verification...

I saw that they are using a function called `solvedCaptcha` and injecting a variable name `payload`. So here is how I solved it:

NOTE: Make sure the driver is currently on the reCAPTCHA page.

```
driver.execute_async_script("var payload = '<enter the job.get_solution_response() here>'; solvedCaptcha(payload);")
```

This async script then calls the page's verification and it reloads the blocked window.

**NOTE**: This CAPTCHA did not have a submit button and was not placed in a form. So using `.submit()` on an item within the driver would not work.

Comment: Im getting a "javascript error: solvedCaptcha is not defined" error. Can you post the link to the source where you found that?

Comment: @h3y4w which source are you looking for?

Comment: where it mentions the function solvedCaptcha.  Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Which site are you trying this for? That was specific to realtor (dot) com. I found it by inspecting the page and looking at the functions going out when solving a captcha. And, successfully, assumed that was the right function because of the “payload” variable

Comment: Nevermind found it.  Had to go through the network and source code in chrome tools to find the anon function.

Comment: The site that I am scraping is built with react js. I have the name of callback method but it is nowhere in the page's script context, so can't call that function. I am able to submit/verify the captcha using browser extension of anticaptcha, but unable to verify using node js API. Browser extension is able to call a method inside react-js component to update its state (setState), but how can I execute that method through node on playwright. Through node I am stuck after feeding solution-hash to textarea. Please suggest some solution to this. Thanks.

Comment: @Shivam - I am not too familiar with your setup, but after you enter the payload to the textarea, you’re saying you can’t trigger the callback?

Comment: Yes, I can't trigger the verifying callback. The callback function is not available in context of page.

Comment: @Shivam - that’s a little out of my depth, but one thing you can try is submitting a captcha like normal, and watching the web browser’s console/source to see what is being triggered. You can submit a failed captcha attempt to see what file gets called and work you way from there. Then, when you see what is pushed through as the payload, you could inject the captcha passed payload into that textarea. Does that help? What site are you hitting?

Comment: Sure, @Shivam  message me and let me know if it works. I’m genuinely curious

Comment: Sure, I will try these approach and revert.

Comment: @PythonReactor I resolved this by loading anticaptcha plugin in playwright at runtime. Browser extension of anticaptcha is able to resolve it, so I used that approach. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Awesome, glad you were able to get it sorted, @Shivam :)

Answer (score 0):

try to sendKeys of \n or Keys.Enter to the textfield.
This was my solution in my projects.
Also this is generic one

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn’t work. I find the element by the selenium driver for the textfield, then try .submit() but it says something about there being no submit component. I even unhide the text field in the HTML code manually and try to press enter but it just gives me a newline

Comment: Can you provide link to the site?

Comment: the link is in the original question. However, I figured it out. I am going to post a solution, hoping it helps anyone who runs across the same issue.

Comment: link to the site with captcha